# writing training and testing data sets into separate files

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

i am training an autoencoder neural network for my work purpose.However i am taking
the image numpy array dataset as input(total samples  16110) and want to split dataset into training and test set using the below `autoencoder.fit` command. Additionally while training the network it is writing like Train on 12856 samples, validate on 3254 samples.

However, i need to save both the training and testing data into separate files. How can i do it?

```
es=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',mode='min',verbose=1,patience=5)
mc=ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5',monitor='val_loss',mode='min',save_best_only=True)

history = autoencoder.fit(dataNoise,dataNoise, epochs=30, batch_size=256, shuffle=256,callbacks=[es,mc], validation_split = 0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the train_test_split function from sklearn. See code below

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_split=.9 # set this  as the % you want for training
train_noise, valid_noise=train_test_split(dataNoise, train_size=train_split, shuffle=True, 
                                          random_state=123)
```

now use train noise as x,y and valid noise for validation data in model.fit

Comment: however i need to do it in keras...can you please suggest how to do it